# Bootstrap grid system - hierarchy of the .container div in relation to other wrappers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have just started working on turning a graphic design into a responsive website using Bootstrap 3. I would like to know the positioning of the `.container` in relation to other wrappers like, e.g. `<nav>`, `<header>`, `<footer>` or semantic custom wrappers like, e.g `<div class="main-content">`, etc.

I am not sure if I should wrap the above mentioned tags in the `.container` div or vice-versa - wrap the `.container` div in those tags.

Essentially, the question is whether the following are equal or there is a preference of order:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-content">
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container">
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

If it depends on the project specifics what markup to choose, what might be potential reasons for choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use following order

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- NAVIGATION -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <!-- (MAIN)CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- FOOTER -->
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

so I can style the navigation `nav` and footer `footer` over the full width (e.g. background) and the content still offers the grid.

**EDIT :** It is based on [Template Business Casual](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/business-casual/).

---

If you wish to style everthing to the same (responsive `.container`-)width you should better put everything inside the `.container`. This also depends on your CSS behind `.main-content`.

Maybe you could check the different [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) (source code) from bootstrap to see which setting/design matches your preferences.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let's assume that you want to introduce the grid to the `<footer>` section of your website and still have it full-width. Then you would have to wrap the footer in `.container-fluid` div. Am I right?

Comment: I expanded the HTML code a little further. Inside the `nav` and `footer` I've got another `.container` class, so the content responds to the devices width and is exact the same width as the main content. If you wish to extent the grid to the full width, you use `.container-fluid` indeed.